# ImportError: with error 'is not a package'

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python 3 getting into ImportError issues.
My project structure is like:

```
cts_sap_polaris/                                                                     
|-- etc                                                                              
|   |-- clean_cts_sap_polaris.yaml                                                   
|   |-- clean_env_variables.tcl                                                      
|   |-- cts_sap_polaris_ha_combined.yaml                                             
|   |-- cts_sap_polaris.yaml                                                         
|   `-- TCL_TESTBED_CONFIGS                                                          
|-- __init__.py                                                                      
|-- jobs
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __pycache__
|   |   `-- run_cts_sap_polaris.cpython-34.pyc
|   `-- run_cts_sap_polaris.py
|-- lib
|   |-- cli_check.py
|   |-- cts_sap_polaris_utils.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- router_show_cts_cmd.py
|   |-- router_show_etherchannel_cmd.py
|   |-- router_show.py
|   |-- utils.py
|   |-- validate_show_output.py
|   `-- wait_for.py
|-- scripts
|   |-- cts_sap_polaris_ha_combined.py
|   |-- cts_sap_polaris.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- __pycache__
|       `-- cts_sap_polaris.cpython-34.pyc
`-- test
    |-- code_snippets
    |-- cts_interface.json
    |-- cts_interface_summary.json
    |-- etherchannel_port_channel.json
    |-- etherchannel_port.json
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- test_cts_sap_cli.py
    `-- test_router_show.py
```

In `scripts/cts_sap_polaris.py` I am trying an import

```
import cts_sap_polaris.lib.cli_check as cli_check
```

Which is throwing this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'cts_sap_polaris.lib'; 'cts_sap_polaris' is not a package.
```

Comment: From what directory are you trying to run this script?  From inside the scripts directory?  You'll either need to run it from the same directory as you were in when you got the tree, or add that same directory to your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Actually, you *would* need to do that, but in your case, the existence of the file named "cts_sap_polaris.py" *also* in the scripts directory will always be found first.  It'll have to be renamed (or moved) as well.

Comment: @jedwards: fantastic!  i was banging my head over this as I was facing the same issue.  Changing the file name helped as you suggested in your second comment.  If you don't mind i'm going to post this as the answer as I believe this will resolve the original problem as well.

Answer (score 83):

Rename cts_sap_polaris.py to something else.

This name conflicts with the package name (which has the same name).

(credit goes to @jedwards on his comment)

Comment: in my case that was app/app.py

Comment: in my case <my_package_name>/<my_package_name>.py 

I wish that Python could detect when this is the case and just prevent it from the outset.

Comment: Why renaming works please even though it's lowercase?

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand, python only searches the current directory and sys.path.
So you can add to the python path at run time.
A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python)

I would suggest you to **try this** ..

```
# scripts/cts_sap_polaris.py
# Add additional path to current sys path
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/path/to/cts_sap_polaris/lib')
import cli_check
```

Let me know if it works.