# How can I import my personnal modules in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pycharm, package

I have a problem with my python modules for a project.
Here's my tree for my project :

```
Documents/Projects/projet/
├── code
│   ├── datas
│   │   ├── Lexique383
│   │   │   └── Lexique383.tsv
│   │   └── Lexique383.zip
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── Correcteur.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── PoCCode.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       ├── Correcteur.cpython-38.pyc
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   └── ui
│       ├── GUI.py
│       ├── GUI.ui
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── Loader.py
│       └── __pycache__
│           └── GUI.cpython-38.pyc
```

The dependencies are like :

- GUI.py uses Correcteur.py
- Loader.py uses GUI.py

I am working on 2 computers for this project, one with PyCharm and one with VSCode.
The thing is I used PyCharm to run Loader.py with a configuration where it added content roots and source roots to PYTHONPATH. But when i went back to my other computer and wanted to check if everything worked fine, I had this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Documents/Projects/projet/code/ui/Loader.py", line 4, in <module>
    import GUI
  File "Documents/Projects/projet/code/ui/GUI.py", line 13, in <module>
    from code.src import Correcteur
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code.src'; 'code' is not a package
```

So I tried to add to my syspath "code", "src" and "ui", but I still have the error.
Without a doubt I did something that didn't work with sys.path but I can't figure out what. Could you please help me on this matter?

Edit :
This is how I added directories to my syspath using pathlib.

Loader.py :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.extend([
    Path(__file__).parents[1].resolve(),
    Path(__file__).parents[1].resolve() / "src"
])
print(sys.path)
import GUI
```

And here is how I imported Correcteur in GUI.py :

```
from code.src import Correcteur
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I tried both of your choices, but none of them worked for me... I still have an error saying "code" is not a package when I try to do ```from code.src import Correcteur```

Comment: Ok, I'll try to do that. But the problem I had with the other thread is that when I go back to VSCode, I can't automatically add content roots et source roots. I'm going to edit my post to add code of how I import and how I add my directories to syspath

Comment: Sorry to consume your time like that, but I still have problems. I deleted my .idea folder and opened again my project. I checked the two boxes in my run confing in PyCharm and everything works. SI I put my .idea in .gitignore and pushed my changes. But once I went to my other computer i still won't work.  Here is my github link to the code if we still can't find an answer : [link to code](https://github.com/cegepmatane/projet-specialise-2022-MoOaAaa/tree/main/code)
Edit : I just saw you comment, I added that to test : ```Documents/Projects/projet, Documents/Projects/projet/code```. Still bug

Comment: @Moa Just to be sure about your environment: Are there any other python files named "code.py" in that package? Or would there be a "code.py" found somewhere else on your path? The fact that the error you're getting says "'code' is not a package" seems to imply that it does **find** something called "code", but it doesn't think it's a package, it thinks it's a module.
Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454852/importerror-with-error-is-not-a-package

Comment: Also, @Moa I think that your github project might be private, because that link gives a 404 right now

Comment: @bad_coder I have the same problem, when I run my main from Loader.py, I have the same message from Pycharm (when I don't check "add content roots" and "add source roots") and VSCode saying my packages aren't actually packages.

Comment: @ncoish , I just saw that sorry (the repository is managed by my school..) I changed the visibility of it, so you should be able to access it now. And I don't have any other files named code.py

Comment: Okay, so the actual error message that you're getting might be masking the issue. It looks like Python has a builtin module named [**code** that it's trying to import](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html). Just to see if you get a different error message, can you try changing your package name to something other than "code"?

Comment: Okay, I got it working! one sec, I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method of adding to `sys.path` should work. The main issue is that you are adding `pathlib.Path` objects to `sys.path`, which only expects strings.

If you just cast the Path object you're trying to add to a string, then a simplified version of your code should work:

In Loader.py

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys
from pathlib import Path
# Note the call to `str(...)` here
sys.path.insert(1, str(Path(__file__).parents[2].absolute()))
print(sys.path)
import GUI
```

Additionally, some of the errors that you are getting are because Python has a builtin module named `code`, which it's importing by mistake, so I would recommend changing your package to have a different name.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I'm going to test it right now

Comment: It's working!!! Thanks to both of you for your help, hope one day I can be like you and help people solve "simple" problems like this one!

Comment: Happy to help! And glad that you're learning. Python packaging tends to be a thorny issue, so great job getting this far!

Comment: Thank you. When I asked help from my teachers asking "I have some problems working from PyCharm and VSCode, I think it's from how I import my packages", we laughed together saying how imports can sometimes be hard to deal with. But I'm really glad I created this question, my project will work on near any computers.
Again thanks a lot, and have a great night / evening / day